# Problemas con merge y dplyr

Tags: r, join

Estoy uniendo dos `data.frames` enormes por una variable en común usando `merge`, y el `data.frame` final tiene muchísimas más líneas que los iniciales, lo cual me sugiere que está duplicando observaciones. Estoy usando:

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by="ID", all=FALSE)
```

Se supone que con ese `all=False` estaría evitando duplicados, ¿no?.

Pondré un ejemplo

```
df1

ID           Ubicación     AñoParto      Hijos
26            0012           2000          2
26            0012           2002          3
26            0012           2005          2
42            0013           2001          1
42            0013           2002          1
42            0013           2007          2
```

Y otro df así

```
ID           Ubicación     AñoParto      Observaciones     Peso
26            0012           2000          1                300
26            0012           2000          2                450
26            0012           2000          3                650
26            0012           2002          1                250
26            0012           2002          2                450
26            0012           2005          1                550
26            0012           2005          2                650
26            0012           2005          3                900
42            0013           2001          1                300
42            0013           2001          2                450
42            0013           2002          1                520
42            0013           2007          1                250
42            0013           2007          2                550
```

Al final lo que quiero es

```
ID           Ubicación     AñoParto      Observaciones     Peso   Hijos
26            0012           2000          1                300    2
26            0012           2000          2                450    2
26            0012           2000          3                650    2
26            0012           2002          1                250    3
26            0012           2002          2                450    3
26            0012           2005          1                550    2
26            0012           2005          2                650    2
26            0012           2005          3                900    2
42            0013           2001          1                300    1
42            0013           2001          2                450    1
42            0013           2002          1                520    1
42            0013           2007          1                250    2
42            0013           2007          2                550    2
```

Lo que me interesa es quedarme con un df final que solamente contenga los elementos que se unieron por la variable común `"nombre"`, pero que me mantenga todas las columnas de `df2`. He intentado también

```
df4 <- semi_join(df1, df2)
```

Pero veo que solamente conserva las variables del `df1`, aunque diría que si deja solamente que tenían en común la variable `"nombre"`.

¿Qué debo hacer?

Answer (score 2):

El problema que tienes, entiendo, es que no has definido correctamente los argumentos del `JOIN`. Al hacer esto:

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by="ID", all=FALSE)
```

Básicamente estás combinando todas las filas que comparten el mismo `ID`, lo cual significa que cada `ID` de `df1` se combinará con cada uno de los `ID` de `df2`, de ahí que obtengas más registros de los que esperas, por ejemplo en `df1` tienes 3 filas con `ID == 26` y 8 filas con el mismo `ID` en `df2`, el resultado final serán 3 * 8 = 24 filas para el `ID == 26`.

Viendo tus datos, lo que me parece es que te falta agregar al argumento del `join` las variables de `Ubicación` y `AñoParto` de la siguiente forma:

```
> merge(df1, df2, by=c("ID", "Ubicación", "AñoParto"))

   ID Ubicación AñoParto Hijos Observaciones Peso
1  26      0012     2000     2             1  300
2  26      0012     2000     2             2  450
3  26      0012     2000     2             3  650
4  26      0012     2002     3             1  250
5  26      0012     2002     3             2  450
6  26      0012     2005     2             1  550
7  26      0012     2005     2             2  650
8  26      0012     2005     2             3  900
9  42      0013     2001     1             1  300
10 42      0013     2001     1             2  450
11 42      0013     2002     1             1  520
12 42      0013     2007     2             1  250
13 42      0013     2007     2             2  550
```

Un detalle interesante de `merge` es que si detecta nombres de columna iguales en ambos `data.frames` los usa como argumento del `join` de forma automática, de forma que en tu caso hacer sencilla esto: `merge(df1, df2)` debiera funcionar igual.